# Perl Imager::QRCode module QR Code colors?

Tags: perl, colors, qr-code

From its page, it lists the following codes but they don't seem to make any differences in colors (always black on white).

```
lightcolor    => Imager::Color->new(255, 255, 255),
darkcolor     => Imager::Color->new(0, 0, 0),
```

I tried to change the color in different combinations but only the black on white QR code is generated.

Did anyone change the colors successfully?

Comment: This is not a bad question, but you could make it even easier for people to help you by posting a https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve that we can just copy & paste and run.

Comment: I double checked the Perl Module page (http://search.cpan.org/~kurihara/Imager-QRCode-0.034/lib/Imager/QRCode.pm) and I found I made a mistake by adding the single quotes (') in the code:

Incorrect:

lightcolor    => 'Imager::Color->new(255, 255, 255)',
darkcolor     => 'Imager::Color->new(0, 0, 0)',

Correct (without the single quotes):

lightcolor    => Imager::Color->new(255, 255, 255),
darkcolor     => Imager::Color->new(0, 0, 0),


The RBG codes can be replaced with HTML color codes (eg. #FF0000, Red).